# How to avoid orphaned headings in CSS columns?

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, multiple-columns

When using CSS3 columns, what strategies can I use to make sure that `h1`-`h6` headers are never orphaned at the bottom of a column?

[Here's a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/KLwfC/). Adjust width and you'll see that despite the presence of the following CSS properties meant to discourage a page-break after the heading, it happens anyways in most browsers.

```
.columnize h1,
.columnize h2,
.columnize h3,
.columnize h4 {
                break-after: avoid;
           page-break-after: avoid;
 -webkit-column-break-after: avoid;
}
```

I even spent time messing with the `orphans` property, but when it works, it works on paragraph lines only, not headings, for some reason.

```
orphans: 2;
```

This is a deal-breaker for me for CSS columns, since text often has headings. Has anybody found any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not likely to be a common want/need, but you've stumbled across an area that I am faced with every day. Our copywriters are big on zero orphans. I made a script that deals with this.

You need to have jQuery, which most websites have... and you just need to run this inside a document ready function. Here goes:

```
/** ORPHAN SLAYER - The world's most irrelevant jQuery plugin **/
var orphanSlayer = {

    targets     : '#your-selector, .another-selector', // These are your selectors, regions where you want the orphans dealt with.
    timer       : 1000 // Delay before running this script, in milliseconds (gives precedence to other scripts)

}

setTimeout(function(){

    $(orphanSlayer.targets).each(function(){

        orphanSlayer.content = $(this).html().split(' ');
        orphanSlayer.last = orphanSlayer.content[orphanSlayer.content.length - 2] + '&nbsp;' + orphanSlayer.content[orphanSlayer.content.length - 1];
        orphanSlayer.content[orphanSlayer.content.length - 2] = orphanSlayer.last;
        orphanSlayer.content.splice((orphanSlayer.content.length - 1), 1);
        orphanSlayer.content = orphanSlayer.content.join(' ');

        $(this).html(orphanSlayer.content); 

    });

}, orphanSlayer.timer );
```

Just copy-paste it into your document ready function, and modify where you see code comments, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the .columnize h3 class:

```
    display: inline;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, [does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/KLwfC/3/). Maybe you were thinking of the `inline-block` fix, but the downside of that is that it prevents the entire section in the `inline-block`ed section from wrapping onto the next column at all. So it may work for very short paragraphs or lists, but does not work for anything with a longer list/paragraph.